# How to send Single Input Field value to Controller with JQuery in Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I want to send a single input form value to database with jQuery in Laravel.

Here is the input field:

```
<input type="text" id="comment">

<button id="cmntSubmit" type="button">Post</button>
```

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).on("click","#cmntSubmit",function() {
    var cmnt = $("#comment").val();

    $.ajax({
      url: "{{ route('laravel_controller') }}",
      data: cmnt,
      success: success,
      dataType: dataType
   });
}
```

How will I send this comment field with jQuery to my Laravel controller and receive the comment field value with `$request`?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use

```
var formdata = new FormData();
       var cmnt = $("#comment").val();

        formdata.append('cmnt ',$("#comment").val());
        formdata.append('_token','<?php echo csrf_token() ?>');
        $.ajax({

            url : '{{ route('laravel_controller') }}',
            type:'POST',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data :formdata,
            success:function(data){


                console.log(data);

            }
        })
```